# How to force rebuild list?

Tags: oop, dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am make random chat app use `FirestoreAnimatedList` (`FirebaseAnimatedList` for Firestore).

In general is work.

But there is flicker when show user avatar (`Icons.account_circle`). For example sometime it show extra `Icon` (wrong) and then later not show (correct).

So I think maybe is because of Widget rebuild? But I no know how solve.

```
final Map<int, dynamic> map = {};
```

...

```
body: FirestoreAnimatedList(
        query: firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
        itemBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
          Animation<double> animation,
          int index,
        ) {

    map[index] = snapshot;


          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: MessageItem(
              index: index,
              document: snapshot,
              map: map,
              onTap: _removeMessage,
            ),
          );
        },

class MessageItem extends StatelessWidget {

…
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              child:

    _sameUser() ?
 new Icon(
      Icons.account_circle
    )
        :
Container()


bool _sameUser () {
  assert(index >= 0);
  assert(map != null);
  return map[index + 1] != null && map[index + 1]['fromUser'] == map[index]['fromUser'];
}
```

Anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: can you show "MessageItem" build method ? 
this well be more helpful

Comment: @abdalmonem I have update. You know issue?

Comment: great , after the first line in the build method `return Container(`
add "key" parameter to the parent container , `key: UniqueKey(),`
also watch this video : [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc] to learn more about "keys"

Comment: @abdalmonem Thanks for reply! I have watch video and try you solution but still have same issue. Icon is show in wrong place. You know other solution? Key is only use for `stateful widget`. `MessageItem` is `stateless`

Comment: i thought its "key" issue , cuz i was face a similar  problem one month ago 
am sorry